# React redux - passing parameters to url - error - Actions must be plain objects

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I want to attach params to react redux fetch action and I searched for many days the redux docs, but even after trying out a few things i am getting this error:

*[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.]*

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-framework-ct2fc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The original action looks like this:

```
export function fetchArticleDetails() {
  return apiAction({
    url: "http://myurl/appApi/2.0.0/getData/1", //1 should be an optional value
    onSuccess: setArticleDetails,
    onFailure: () => console.log("Error occured loading articles"),
    label: FETCH_ARTICLE_DETAILS
  });
}

function setArticleDetails(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return dispatch({ 
    type: SET_ARTICLE_DETAILS,
    payload: data
  });
}
```

i tried to set the param directly

```
export function fetchArticleDetails(id)
   ...
   url: `http://myurl/appApi/2.0.0/getData/${id}`,
```

or some variations to put the params in the payload directly

```
function setArticleDetails(data) {
  console.log(data);
  return dispatch({ 
    type: SET_ARTICLE_DETAILS,
    payload: data,
    userid: id
  });
}
```

All this results in the same error. Anyone have an idea where to place the dynamic data to solve it?
Another idea could be to set the params in my reducer maybe?

Update store/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import apiMiddleware from "../middleware/api";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware));
window.store = store;
export default store;
```

update: middleware/api.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import { API } from "../actions/types";
import { accessDenied, apiError, apiStart, apiEnd } from "../actions/api";

const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  next(action);

  if (action.type !== API) return;

  const {
    url,
    method,
    data,
    accessToken,
    onSuccess,
    onFailure,
    label,
    headers
  } = action.payload;
  const dataOrParams = ["GET", "DELETE"].includes(method) ? "params" : "data";

  // axios default configs
  axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL || "";
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

  if (label) {
    dispatch(apiStart(label));
  }

  axios
    .request({
      url,
      method,
      headers,
      [dataOrParams]: data
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch(onSuccess(data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(apiError(error));
      dispatch(onFailure(error));

      if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
        dispatch(accessDenied(window.location.pathname));
      }
    })
    .finally(() => {
      if (label) {
        dispatch(apiEnd(label));
      }
    });
};

export default apiMiddleware;
```

function apiAction()

```
function apiAction({
  url = "",
  method = "GET",
  data = null,
  accessToken = null,
  onSuccess = () => {},
  onFailure = () => {},
  label = "",
  headersOverride = null
}) {
  return {
    type: API,
    payload: {
      url,
      method,
      data,
      accessToken,
      onSuccess,
      onFailure,
      label,
      headersOverride
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk for async operations ?

Comment: as seen in my updated question only redux. Ok, now i have to implement redux-thunk and write new actions?

Comment: @DanielRichter Can you share the `apiMiddleware` code?

Comment: yes of course, question updated. as you can see `const dataOrParams` is defined so thatswhy i thought i can set params direct.

Comment: @DanielRichter Thanks. Can you also share the `apiAction` code? And if you could share a minimal reproducible example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/), it would be easier to debug.

Comment: function is added. i'll try to create a codesandbox

Comment: @DanielRichter Thanks. The shared CodeSandbox does have some issues. Can you fix them? You might want to use the React Native template.

Comment: its updated. in method `fetchArticleDetails()` in actions/index.js you can switch the last url parameter or leave it blank. thats it what i  need dynamic by userid

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-framework-ct2fc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code. `apiMiddleware` should only pass the action to the next middleware in the chain if it's not of type `API`.

```js
const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => (next) => (action) => {
  if (action.type !== API) {
    return next(action)
  }

  // do stuff
}
```

Since the `apiMiddleware` dispatches what `onFailure` returns, the function has to return an object. In `fetchArticleDetails`, you're passing `() => console.log("Error occured loading articles")` causing `apiMiddleware` to dispatch `undefined`.

```js
export function fetchArticleDetails(id) {
  return apiAction({
    url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`,
    onSuccess: setArticleDetails,
    onFailure: (error) => ({
      type: FETCH_ARTICLE_ERROR,
      payload: error
    }),
    label: FETCH_ARTICLE_DETAILS
  })
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-lalande-humxx?file=/src/main.tsx)

---

I would strongly recommend using [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com) to simplify data fetching, managing, and syncing server state.

Comment: Thats exactly what im looking for. Many Thx. I'll take a look to React Query, thx for it. One Question: the middleware doesnt contains a way to send post data when im looking right, so that i can extend the middleware with a body param in axios.request() to send post data?

Comment: @DanielRichter Aren't you already doing that with `dataOrParams` in the middleware? Not sure if I'm missing something.